# Indicate the mark in a buffer in Emacs

Tags: mark

Is there a way of visually indicating mark and previous locations of mark in a buffer using only vanilla Emacs without any external package?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built-in, but you can write a function to do that: does that count as an external package?

Comment: Can you motivate the request a bit, by saying why you want this, e.g., what are you really trying to do (or do you just want to see it, for no special reason)?

Comment: Is `C-x C-x` followed by `C-x C-x` not handy enough, to see where the mark is?

Comment: I had wanted to show the point for pedagogic purposes. No, a function does not count as an external package.

Comment: Just to note that `C-x C-x' does not show the mark although one can infer the position of mark by invoking it. A mark by definition is a visible impression that indicates or records. It seems to me to be a limitation that Emacs does not show the mark.